# Reading and writing QgsLayerMetadata

Tags: pyqgis, metadata

[QgsMapLayer.metadata()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.metadata) says that it "Returns a reference to the layer’s metadata store." as a [QgsLayerMetadata](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsLayerMetadata.html) object.

If I use it on a new layer (or the `world` easteregg layer), there won't be metadata, e.g. no licenses:

```
>>> layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>> metadata = layer.metadata()
>>> metadata.licenses()
['']
```

If I edit the layer's metadata via the GUI, the change won't be reflected in the `QgsLayerMetadata` object I got:

[image]

```
>>> metadata.licenses()
['']
```

Vice-versa, if I edit the metadata from Python, the changes won't be reflected in the GUI:

```
metadata.setLicenses([""])
metadata.licenses()
['']
```

[image]

This makes me think that either the documentation is wrong and it is not a reference to the layer's metadata store but a copy (or I don't understand the terminology) or that I am using the API wrong.

How do I properly read and write a QGIS layer's metadata using Python?

I am looking for an authoritative answer (re-getting `layer.metadata()` all the time feels wrong, as does using `layer.setMetadata()`, as the docs say we got a reference).

Comment: I may not be an expert in c++ at all, but I don't think the documentation is necessarily wrong. In c++ terminology what you receive from this method is indeed a reference, meaning you get the `QgsLayerMetadata` object - not a pointer to it, nor a copy of it. 
However, python does not care about concepts such as references and pointers, therefore I believe that sip will create a Python object that wraps the corresponding c++ instance, giving you essentially a copy.